# where should I implement SeekBar.onSeekBarChangeListener?

Tags: java, android, listener, seekbar

I'm inflating an xml resource ant set it as the view of an `AlertDialoge`. the xml contains a `SeekBar` and I want to define `SeekBar.onSeekBarChangeListener` for that. I tried to implement it in the `onCreate()` method of the activity in which the `AlertDialoge` is going to be showed, but the app gets force closed. where to implement the listener ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code it's quite difficult. But here's a little hint.

You should have some code like this, where you inflate your dialog's content view:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myAlertDialog, (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
```

Use your view to get your SeekBar instance and assign your listener:

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.mySeekBar);
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {...});
```